# Buddy cop movie with one partner a "zombie"

Tags: identify-this-movie

I wrote "zombie" in quotation marks, because for the most part he wasn't mindless. But I'm getting ahead of myself.

An **American** film I saw **somewhere mid-90s** (might be tad older, of course. **80s**?). In **color** and very bright, as if it **took place in LA** or somewhere else in California. **Or maybe Florida**. Somewhere in USA where swimming pools by the houses are common, because there definitely is a scene around a swimming pool.

It's a **buddy cop movie** about two cops (or detectives?), both white male, but it has a **supernatural twist**: in their investigation they discover some serum? or technology? that **reanimates the dead**. Or prevent death, **make a person immortal**? Something like that. They discover how it works because in the film one of the cop partners actually dies (is drowned, I think, but not sure) but he **remains alive and active**. Not brain dead like a zombie - he's still fully doing his job as a cop. I remember him discovering that when he cuts himself, **he doesn't bleed**.

There's also some **lady helping them in the investigation**. Not a cop. Scientist, maybe?

Only at some point later in the film that "zombie" cop really dies (I think maybe it's at this point where he's drowned - I vaguely remember his head in a jar of water?) and when is reanimated, he's mindless and tries to kill his partner and the lady. I think they manage to get to him to remember who he was.

That's all I remember. Will be very thankful for your help.

Comment: The title reminded me of *Shaun of the Dead*, but the details are very different.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the sci-fi comedy [Dead Heat](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094961/combined) from 1988.

> Roger Mortis [yuk yuk] and Doug Bigelow are cops that are chasing crooks that are dead serious about crime. Or should I say they are chasing dead crooks perpetrating serious crimes? Seems some nutcase has learned how to bring back the dead and is sending them on crime sprees. Now these indestructable goons are in the way of officers Mortis and Bigelow. To even things up, when Mortis is killed (in the line of duty, of course) he gets a jump start from the Resurrection machine and takes the fight to the zombie bad guys.

It contains everything you mentioned, including the partner drowned in a fish tank and later resurrected and almost killing his partner before suddenly  remembering who he is. They're helped by *two* women, a coroner and a PR lady; it's a sort of weird precursor to *Men in Black* and *RIPD*. The movie stars Treat Williams and Joe Piscopo in the lead roles, Vincent Price as the villain (who else) and oddly, [Shane Black](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000948/) in a small cameo (his brother wrote the script). Here's the trailer: